# A GTF annotation for GRCH375d version

Tags: rna-seq, sequence-alignment, sequence-annotation, gtf

I have been given a bunch of .bam files, that come from the alignment on GRCh37d5 of human genome by Star tool. I want to extract raw read counts from these bam files by FEATURECOUNTS tool so I need a GTF. I googled a lot but I did not find GTF for GRCh37d5. I used another GTFs and I obtained weird features. Please one of you help me in finding this specific GTF. I converted a bam to fastq and I used Salmon to quantify gene expression by a transcripome.fasta but rate of mapping was 0.06

Comment: It's helpful to know that GRCh37 refers to the **G**enome **R**eference **C**onsortium assembly of the **h**uman genome, version **37** (should be equivalent to hg19 from UCSC). I've never seen "5d" though. Often times GRC will introduce "patch" updates with minor changes that don't change the primary coordinate system—that's what `p13` refers to in kayvee's answer below.

Comment: @DanielStandage Might be of interest to you: https://www.biostars.org/p/328824/#330791

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most recent annotation of GRCh37 assembly by NCBI RefSeq is here: https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/Homo_sapiens/GRCh37.p13_interim_annotation/

You can download the annotation in GFF3 format from that path and use it with featurecounts tool by first converting it to the SAF format using the commands shown below:

```
$ zgrep -v '^#' annotation.gff.gz \
    | awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t";OFS="\t"}($3=="exon"){print $1,$4,$5,$7,$9}' \
    | sed -r 's/ID.*GeneID:([0-9]*).*/\1/g' \
    | awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t";OFS="\t"}{print $5,$1,$2,$3,$4}'
    > annotation.saf
```

You should confirm that the chromosome sequence identifiers in the BAM file and the SAF file match. NCBI annotation has identifiers in the accession.version format whereas UCSC uses `chr#` format and Ensembl uses `#`. For this, you can use the `-A` parameter from `featureCounts`. Assuming that your BAM file uses UCSC-style identifiers, you can generate a 'chromosome name alias file' that can be used with featureCounts as follows:

```
## get NCBI assembly report for GRCh37
wget -nv ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCF/000/001/405/GCF_000001405.24_GRCh37.p12/GCF_000001405.24_GRCh37.p12_assembly_report.txt

## generate chr_alias.csv file
grep -v '^#' GCF_000001405.24_GRCh37.p12_assembly_report.txt \
    | dos2unix \
    | awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t";OFS=","}($10!="na"){print $10,$7}' \
    > chr_alias.csv
```

Comment: I didn't know about "SAF" format. I use gff with FeatureCounts. For the record, according to https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Rsubread/versions/1.22.2/topics/featureCounts: "The SAF annotation format has five required columns, including GeneID, Chr, Start, End and Strand. These columns can be in any order".